# RxJava2 execute Completable and Observable simultaneously and handle result from both

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

I have one Completable and Observable that emits items. I have to combine them. Some kind of Observable.combineLatest but with Completable and Observable. 
So logic is: if Observable emit item first, when Completable is not complete, it should wait for Completable (not ignore), if Completable is complete, then items from Observable should be handled.

I tried convert Completable into Observable but that Observable does not emit onNext, so Observable.zip, Observable.combineLatest, etc does not worked.

Code that works for me:

myCompletable.andThen(myObservable).subscribe()

But I don't call completable and observable asynchronously. I just wait until completable completes.Is it possible to run Completable and Observable asynchronously and handle observable items when Complitable complites?

Comment: What should happen if `Observable` emits more than one item before the `Completable` completes? Do you need to keep all prior items?

Comment: No, i don't. I don't need flowable for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `myCompletable` to an `Observable` and use `.defaultIfEmpty` to guarantee there will be at least one item emitted. Check this example:

```
val myObservable: Observable<Long> = ...
val myCompletable: Completable = ...

Observable.combineLatest(
    myObservable
    myCompletable.toObservable<Long>().defaultIfEmpty(0L),
    BiFunction<Long, Long, Long> { a, b -> a}
)
.subscribe()
```

Note that only the last item emitted by `myObservable` will be kept with this method, as suggested in the comment.

Comment: In that case, I got default value. I think it because Completable (Hot Completable - CompletableSubject in my case) is not emit items because onComplete() called.